# What exactly are DML triggers?

Tags: sql

How to apply trigger code to a table to track the number of modifications to each column? 
I'm new to using SQL and using triggers.

Comment: This would be a good thing to research online before hitting up a Q&A site, there are plenty of resources out there with write ups on triggers.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Those are DML, not DDL.  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_1001.htm

Comment: OP - Google "DDL trigger" and you will find pages that explain.  Also Google "sql trigger" ... because what you seem to be asking about are not **DDL** triggers.

Comment: In SQL Server, you can `CREATE TRIGGER FOR ALTER_TABLE` and then examine the details of the ALTER_TABLE event with the EVENTDATA function. That should give you plenty to google... if you're using SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

**Below is example where employee address is tracked:**

Step 1
DDL:

```
create table emp(name varchar(20), address varchar (20));
create table Audit_address (address varchar(20), updated_date date);
```

Step 2:
DML:

```
insert into emp values ('Dharminder', 'Pune');
```

Step 3 To create Trigger:

```
delimiter //
  CREATE TRIGGER Audit_address AFTER UPDATE ON emp
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Audit_address VALUES(old.address, CURDATE());
    END//
```

Step 4:

```
delimiter ;
```

Step 5

```
update emp set address = 'Chandigarh';
```

Step 6

```
Select * from Audit_address;
```

Output:

Address       Updated_date "Pune"       "2018-01-31"